# Неожиданный токен

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Найдено 3 ошибок при анализе.

```
Неожиданный токен. (near "," at position 55)
Неожиданный токен. (near "values" at position 64)
Неизвестный оператор. (near "values" at position 64)
```

SQL запрос:

```
INSERT INTO `user_review` SET (id_user,name,review_text,rating) values ('1','Вася','отлично','5')
```

Comment: Сколько бы Вы не придумывали свой собственный синтаксис - сервер никогда не согласится его понимать. [INSERT statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html). `INSERT .. SET` и `INSERT .. VALUES` - это две РАЗНЫЕ формы запроса, которые не объединяются в единую.

Comment: простыми словами - удалите SET и всё заработает)